# Anchor/Glue point to a character/word in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to enhance a code sample in my presentation by an arrow connector linking two specific parts of the text. The characters are not a natural target for a connector so when there is a change to the slide (e.g. font size change), the arrow does not adapt. That makes it nonsensical until manually updated.

Is there any way to set a word (or character) of text as a "connectable entity"?

Comment: Use a textbox for both reference points that's possibly almost invisible?

Comment: @Seth I can't see this could be the solution because in PowerPoint (at least in 2016 edition) the text box can't be aligned "in line with text" as it is possible in Word.

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do? Are you doing some kind of automatic changing? With textboxes you would also need to take care to update the text within them individually. I'm wondering about the bigger picture as the approaches I can think of all require some manual intervention. Using linked text boxes you could use them as a "lense" you put on top of the important parts (background transparency). So you would need to manually adjust them but not have to recreate any arrows. On the other hand that's probably going to be easy enough.

Comment: @Seth I just want to have the arrow-decorated text of code robust to for example font size or template change. Later add of any bullet entry above the text repositions lines as well. So the "lense" textboxes must then be manually repositioned (no difference to the original case of a standalone arrow).

Comment: You might want to add that to your question. As it is I was assuming you were talking about cases where you actually replaced (parts) of the code. Which might have different challenges in comparison.

Comment: If you are fairly familiar with VBA in PPT, you could probably write a bit of code that checks each arrow for a tag that contains the text it's supposed to point to and possibly the name of the shape that contains said text, then locates the text within that shape and finally uses the found text's BoundingBox to reposition the arrow head.  This is not a beginner's project, though.